# kdb: how to match complex strings

Tags: regex, match, kdb

I have a table like this

```
t:([] c1:til 5;c2:("abcde";"cdefg";"ecbda";"bsdee";"dbzeya"))
c1 c2      
-----------
0  "abcde" 
1  "cdefg" 
2  "ecbda" 
3  "bsdee" 
4  "dbzeya"
```

I want to select the rows that contain the string `"*b*d*"` in c2, this is how I do it:

```
pattern:"*b*d*"
select from t where c2 like pattern
```

but reported an error.

```
nyi: Not yet implemented
```

I found this error from the KX official website [KX official website](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/regex/#like), but there is no way to solve this problem, what should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-posting answer from:

https://community.kx.com/t5/kdb-and-q/Why-regular-expression-doesn-t-work-with-bracket/m-p/13492

kdb+ does not implement full regex.

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/regex/

It supports `?` `*` `[]` `^`

If you want full support you can use the C interface to bring in external libraries

- https://code.kx.com/q/basics/regex/#regex-libraries
- https://code.kx.com/developer/libraries/regular-expression-pcre2/
- https://github.com/KxSystems/ffi/blob/master/examples/pcre.q

Or Python:

- https://kx.com/blog/advanced-pattern-matching-and-text-manipulation-in-kdb-with-embedpy/

Answer (score 2):

A state machine would work in raw q (though they aren't the most efficient):

```
q)m:({0};{1+x="b"};{2+x="d"};{3});
q)select from t where 3=1 m/'c2
c1 c2
----------
0  "abcde"
2  "ecbda"
3  "bsdee"
```

EDIT: adding explanation for the state engine:

It defines a set of states to be in (represented by the lambas) where the goal is to get to the final state, in this example state 3. A string that satisfies this particular regex should end up in state 3. The logic steps through each character in the string and tests it against the relevant lambda starting from lambda 1, i.e. `1 m/"abcde"`. Each lambda is then a test which determines if the string moves to the next state or not, i.e. `{1+x="b"}` will remain in state 1 if the next char isn't "b", but will move to state 2 if `x="b"`. And so on

Comment: This is interesting, could you explain me exactly how this  works?

Comment: Yes, see edit above

Comment: Thank you much - this is much clearer now :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
select from t where{0<last deltas(first where x="b";last where x="d")}each c2
```

Comment: I did it with external library.```pattern:".*b.*d.*"
select  from t where .pcre2.test[pattern;c2;::]```